# Modeling N to N associations in Go on the App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm attempting to write a webapp in Go using the Google App Engine, and I have a question about modeling relationships using the datastore.

I know in Python I would be able to model a relationship using a db.referenceProperty().  What I can't seem to figure out is how to make a similar association using the Go APIs.

Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Key as a property in the entity: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference.html

Something like this (I don't know Go so bear with me):

```
type Employee struct {
    Name     string
    Boss     *Key
}

employee := Employee{
    Name:     "John Doe",
    Boss:     key    // a key to some other entity
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Peter, you were definitely on the right track.  I *think* I've figured this out.  I haven't really tested this, but it appears to be right in the datastore viewer. What I have right now looks like this (ignoring error checking for the example):

```
type Boss struct {
    Name, Uuid string
}

type Employee struct {
    Name, Uuid string,
    Boss *datastore.Key
}

boss := &Boss {
    Name:  "Pointy Haired Boss",
    Uuid:  <<some uuid>>,
}

dilbert := &Employee {
    Name: "Dilbert",
    Uuid: <<some uuid>>,
    boss: nil,
}

datastore.Put(context, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(context, "Boss", nil), bossman)
query := datastore.NewQuery("Boss").Filter("Uuid =", bossMan)
for t := query.Run(ctx); ; {
    var employee Employee
    key, err := t.Next(&employee)
    if err == datastore.Done {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error %s", err)
    }
    dilbert.Boss = key
}
datastore.Put(context, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(context, "Employee", nil), dilbert)
```